# Xcode App Distribution with Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I am currently trying to distribute my Xcode app onto an iPhone with test flight. The website has a tutorial on how to generate the IPA, and so far I'm stuck at step 4. Here is step 4:

4) Go to the Build Settings tab and scroll down to the Code Signing section and expand the Provisioning Profile settings. For the two default build configurations (Debug and Release), select your Development Provisioning Profile for Debug and your Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile for Release.

For starters, when I go to the Code Signing section when I hit Build settings, there is no Provisioning profile setting. Instead, there is a Code Signing Identity setting. Also, The development provisioning profile and the Ad hoc provisioning file don't show up for me when I click on Debug or Release. All that shows up is iPhone Developer and iPhone Distribution.

How can I  create a Development Provisioning profile and an Ad Hoc provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have development certificate and Provisioning profile for development with devices UDID. if you don't have them create new development certificate and Provisioning profile.

Open Test flight and create an app with some name. It will generate a unique identifier for your app with code to implement. copy code and paste in app delegate.m then  create an IPA using those files.

Once you create IPA file open Test flight it will ask you to drag drop the IPA file, once you drop your IPA it will process uploading and shows list of devices and user name. Your device will be either in users name section or in UDID'd section  select the device you want to send through test flight and send.

Comment: creation of  development certificate and Provisioning profile for development use this [link] http://developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

Go through following steps (Details of each steps is linked with Apple guideline)

1. [Configuring Your Xcode Project for Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW1)

   - Configure Identity and Team Settings
   - Set Bundle ID
   - [Create Team Provisioning Profile.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW7)
   - Assign the Xcode Project to a Team
   - Select a signing identity
2. [Maintaining Identifiers, Devices, and Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW1)

   - Register App IDs
   - Register Devices Using Your Developer Account
   - Create Development/Ad Hoc/Production Provisioning Profiles
   - Download Provisioning Profiles in Xcode
3. [Export Your App for Testing (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

   - Register Test Device
   - Archive Your App
   - Export Your App for Testing Outside the Store
4. [Distributing Your App Using TestFlight (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html)

Answer (score 0):

You create provisioning profiles on http://developer.apple.com. Here, you need to log into your Apple developer account and go through the process of creating an AdHoc Distribution profile. This involves creating a certificate, adding devices, then generating a profile that uses the new certificate and a list of devices. You then download that profile, choose it in the Build Settings of your app for Release builds, and then archive your build. From here, you can then send out your app to your TestFlight users.